# How can I keep an event from firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `HTML` that is structured like this,

`<ul>
   <li class="liSortable">List Item</li>
   <li class="liSortable">List Item</li>
   <li class="liSortable">List Item</li>
   <li class="liSortable">List Item</li>
</ul>`

I have some javascript that looks like this,

```
$('.liSortable').not('.pseudo').draggable(listDragOption);
$('.liSortable').bind(
    "collision",
    function(event, ui) {

    }
)
.on("mousedown", function(e){
    console.log("!!!");
    $(this).draggable('disable')
    app.startAccessoryMoveAction($(this), e);
});
```

Clicking on a `.liSortable` fires 5 times I assume because there are 5 matching elements, how can I make it only fire once relative to the `.liSortable` that has been clicked?

Comment: How do we reproduce this...?

Comment: Strange, I attempted to reproduce it but couldn't get it to. See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/apa8qovq/

Comment: A.), you can easily chain that all together. B.) is any of your content (namely the JS) being created dynamically?

Comment: there are only 4 matching elements